# EventAggregator multiple fired on one event

Tags: c#, uwp, prism, windows-10-universal

I have the code on one of the viewModel calling event on the MainPageViewModel. When I do subscribe with "TRUE" like

```
eventAggregator type.GetEvent<UpdateUserBooksEvent>().Subscribe(str => 
{
    GetUserBooks();
}, true);
```

and then move several times between different pages, then when this event is called, it fires on the MainPageViewModel several times. (Maybe MainPageVM created multiple times?)

If I subscribe without "true" like

```
eventAggregator type.GetEvent<UpdateUserBooksEvent>().Subscribe(str => 
{
    GetUserBooks();
});
```

and go on a couple of pages, then the event is not fired. (Maybe MainPageVM cleared by Garbage Collector?).

How to make an event not worked multiple times? Or fired before navigate far then 1-2 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `true` means `keepSubscriberReferenceAlive` - i.e. if you pass `true` your subscriber will receive the event even though he *should* be dead by now, because it isn't referenced anymore. That means, if you publish the event, all subscribers that ever subscribed (with `true`) will receive the event. If you navigate from view A to view B and each time a new view model B subscribes, all those view models B will receive the event.

If you want to receive the event on a view model that isn't active anymore (and therefore collected unless you subscribe with `true`), you probably want to subscribe to the event somewhere else to react to it (in a service?) or not subscribe at all (a collected view model doesn't need to update anything).

Comment: How to implement service in UWP which will always accessible from any VM anytime?

Comment: Register it as singleton with unity (or whichever container you use) and have it injected in your view models as dependency.